# CssClass value not found for non-MVC ASP.NET form

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2008

I know that people have had some trouble with undefined CssClass values when using partial classes in ASP.NET MVC.  My project is not MVC, however, and I am including a .css file that is in the root folder of my project, yet a referenced class value still results in a warning in VS 2008.

In my .aspx file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
        <!-- ... -->
        <link media="all" href="~MyStyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body id="bodyTag" vlink="#666666" alink="#666666" link="#666666" bgcolor="#ffffff" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="~Scripts\Somecript_v1.js"></script>
        <!-- form, table ... -->
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="4" CssClass="cellclass">
```

Then, in the same folder as the .aspx, in "MyStyles.css", I have defined:

```
.cellclass
{
    border-right: #aeaeae 1px solid;
    border-top: #aeaeae 1px solid;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 11px;
/* etc. */
```

Yet I get the warning, "The class or CssClass value is not defined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
<link media="all" href="~MyStyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

You cannot use the `~` syntax in non `runat="server"` controls. You can't use it in `link` or `script` tags anyway. So your `href` should look like:

```
<link media="all" href="MyStyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

For security, in case you move the file aspx file later you would be advised to include the full path from the root of the website starting with a `/` e.g. `/MyFolder/MyStyles.css`

Comment: When I remove the tilde, I get the warning "File 'mystyles.css' was not found."

Comment: Then you need to include the path. Without path info ASP.NET looks for the file in the root of the website not the folder the aspx file is in. Add a path to the href or move the stylesheet to the root of the website.

Comment: If I'm building a new app in VS 2008, under Win 7, the project is created in C:\Users\myname\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\myproject.  I haven't deployed yet, so I really don't know what you mean by "the root of the website", and I don't know what the href path would be relative to.

Comment: The root of the website would be where the web.config lives. In your case most likely the myproject folder.

Comment: Okay, so I verified that the stylesheet is in the same folder as the web.config.  Changed the reference to look like this:

<link media="all" href="./MyStyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

yet get the same "not defined" error.

Comment: You don't need the dot in the path. The dot means "here" so "./MyStyles.css" is the same as "MyStyles.css". What you need to say  is "from the root" which is "/MyStyles.css.